# How to zero fill with implied zeroes in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to show 9 characters - zero fill with an implied decimal.  For instance, $5.88 should show 000000588.  I've tried entering =TEXT(a1,"00000000) - I end up getting 000000006.  I need to see the full amount without the decimal.  Help and thanks!

Comment: Try =TEXT(A1*100,"00000000")

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what value the cell is going to have, you are probably more suited to using a formula like this:

```
=TEXT(A1*(10^(LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))))),"00000000")
```

`LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))` - Works out the difference between the position of the decimal place and the last digit

5.84 becomes 584 which will then become 00000584.

Please note: This formula will only work on values that have a decimal place in the cell. The cells should be formatted to include the `.`